# Add a column to a table according to some query results

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables, say `faq_categories` and `faq_category_relations`. First I do a query in tabel `faq_category_relations`, like

```
SELECT category_id 
FROM faq_category_relations
WHERE faq_id = 2;
```

And the `result_a` is

```
--------------
|category_id |
--------------
|          2 |
--------------
|          3 |
--------------
```

Then I want to query table `faq_categories` and add one column `checked`, the value of which is set according to `result_a`(that is, if `faq_categories.id` is one of the values in result_a, set the `checked` to be `true`, else `false`), to the query results.

Till now I only come up with:

```
SELECT *, IF((faq_categories.id is one of result_a), 'true', 'false') AS checked
FROM faq_categories
```

And have no idea how to continue..

I know I can do that trick in PHP after retrieving the query data, but there must be some simple way to directly return the query results I needed.

EIDT:

The result should come out like this:

```
---------------------------
|category_id |    checked |
---------------------------
|          1 |      false |
---------------------------
|          2 |       true |
---------------------------
|          3 |       true |
---------------------------
|          4 |      false |
---------------------------
|          5 |      false |
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates in `faq_category_relations`, then you can do this with a `left outr join` and a `case` expression:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (case when cr.category_id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end) as checked
FROM faq_categories c left outer join
     faq_category_relations cr
     on c.category_id = cr.category_id and
        cr.faq_id = 2;
```

I am also assuming that you just need the value in a query and not as a new column in the table.

Comment: Works great! I had no idea that `CASE` can be used here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
select c.*, cr.category_id is not null checked
from faq_categories c
left join faq_category_relations cr
  on c.category_id = cr.category_id
where cr.faq_id = 2
```

This works because with left joins, the values in the joined columns will be null if there's no join, so testing for not null will tell you if the category was listed in the other table.

If you want you can move the condition on `faq_id` into the join condition, which can be done by changing `where` to `and` in the above query.

Comment: Thanks, But this only comes out with 2 records with the added column `checked`, while I need the whole faq_categories table(more than 20 records in total).